# Отсутствует компонент постоения графиков TChart

Tags: delphi, ide, teechart, delphi-10-tokyo

У меня версия среды `Embarcadero® Delphi 10.2 Professional Update2`. Я пытаюсь перенести проект с `Delphi 2009` на `Delphi 10.2`
В палитре отсутствую компоненты построения графиков `TChart`. Соответствующих `*.bpl` тоже найти не могу у себя на компьютере.

Answer (score 5):

Была такая же проблема. В Component-Install Packages отсутствовал TChart и не было *.bpl файла. 
На главной странице (Welcome Page) есть вкладка Expand and Extend => Platforms and Extensions Manager. В открывшимся окне выбираем вкладку Additional Options. Ставим галочку на TeeChart Standard, нажимаем кнопку Apply
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

TChart входит во все редакции, кроме Starter. Видимо, при инсталляции он был не отмечен.

Можно зайти в Component-Install Packages, найти TChart в списке и сделать Add